# What is it called when a speaker accidentally merges two words?

Tags: portmanteau-words

There is a word to describe the action of accidentally mixing two words together, such as exclaiming *trampede* when struggling to explain what cattle do. The speaker tries to say one thing, but a related concept interferes right at the moment of speech, and as a result the two words come out as somewhat garbled together. Importantly, however, the garbled speech is understandable and not non-sensical. Referring to the above case, we all instantly see that cattle *stampede*, and as a result can *trample* what is in their path.

Several years ago I came across the precise word for this, and I cannot find it again. It is not *portmanteau*, as that's a word I have known all my life and thus I would not have been pleased to discover this new-- now forgotten-- word. The important distinction between *portmanteau* and the above concept is its accidental, incorrect nature.

P.S. I understand that technically the words I described might be portmanteaus, in the same sense that squares are rectangles. However, in the identical sense that a person might seek *square* as a better word to describe *rectangles of equal side length*, so I search for this.

Comment: Are you sure the word you heard before wasn't ***eggcorn*** or ***mondegreen**?* Those are certainly common terms that come very *close* to the exact context you describe. But so does ***malapropism***.

Comment: The difficulty is that terms like *blend, eggcorn, mondegreen, malapropism* refer to the intentional/accidental/incidental combination/confusion of written or spoken words with *different meanings*. You case seems like a type of linguistic *interference* where the brain comes up with two synonyms and the speaker doesn't decide on one in time, so the utterance is more or less a sudden, random mishmash.

Comment: 'Malmanteau' may have achieved wordness, but apparently includes one neologism-part. Have you done any research (eg looking up synonyms [lists often include near relatives] of 'portmanteau')?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I do the thesaurus dive about once a year, but alas no joy as of yet. The worst part is that I'm fairly certain it was A Word A Day word many years back, but I can't find it in those archives.

Comment: @DjinTonic, that's exactly right, and excellently expressed.

Comment: inadvertent telescoping: https://www.encyclopedia.com/humanities/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/telescoping Or **phonological cluttering** https://toofastforwords.com/symptoms-cluttering/main/types-of-cluttering/ [considered a disorder]

Answer (score 4):

In psycholinguistics, that might be referred to as a speech error — a “blend” of the unintentional type. For example:

> Blend  “errors” involve two different lexical units that are planned
> for the same slot in a phrase and their phonological forms blend
> together in a single unit:
>
> (11) That’s a great big [fɑpɑ] bear! (father and papa) (Jaeger 2005)
>
> This example from a child resulted in a blend of the words *father*
> and *papa*, two related lexical items planned for that position in the
> sentence.
>
> <sub>Source: [To “Err” is Human: The Nature of Phonological “Errors” in
> Language
> Development](https://www.swarthmore.edu/sites/default/files/assets/documents/linguistics/2008_Landi.pdf)</sub>

Portmanteaus are blends too, but they are intentional.

That’s the best I can do. But before I go, I thought I would offer a word I accidentally invented years ago — in a nomenclature meta moment:

> **termanalogy** *n.*
>
> **1.** An improvised word similar to the one you were aiming to say.

Comment: Candidates are candidates until they receive acceptance into the lexicon.

Answer (score 3):

**lexical/word blend errors**

> **Word blend errors** should be examined for evidence to support this hypothesis, but the facts in the MIT-CU corpus are obscured by the
> number of cases that blend at a shared phoneme (e.g., "prubble" for
> [problem + trouble]), making it impossible to determine whether the
> blended portions correspond to the initial consonant sequence and the
> rest of the word or not. *Pyscholinguistics: Critical Concepts in
> Psychology* [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Psycholinguistics/vZ2ChXNfZUQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22word%20blend%20errors%22&pg=PA109&printsec=frontcover).

> In paradigmatic **lexical blend errors**, the most common semantic
> relationship for the adults was synonyms...The frequency of synonyms
> is what is expected, given the definition of **lexical blends**: if two
> lexical items are competing for the same slot in the utterance, then
> the most likely situation will be that the two words will convey
> nearly the same meaning. *Kids' Slips* [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Kids_Slips/wcZpn_OkR48C?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22lexical%20blends%22).

> While speech errors come in many forms... Semantic errors are of two
> types, word substitutions and **word blends**.
> ...
> As discussed in
> 2.3.4, substitution and **blend errors** frequently involve words that are semantically related in a paradigmatic way. This leads many to the
> conclusion that the mapping errors involved here arise from the
> "proximity" of paradigmatically related words in a semantically
> organized lexicon.  *Semantic Relations and the Lexicon: Antonymy,
> Synonymy, and Other Paradigms* (2003) [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Semantic_Relations_and_the_Lexicon/7pAIpz87jbEC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=paradigmatic%20lexical%20blend%20errors&pg=PA238&printsec=frontcover)

**word blend errors** is an index entry in this last ref.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find the English word for this but I do know we have one in Dutch (my mother tongue). It's called *contaminatie*, which is a funny word, since it also carries the same meaning as the word contamination does. Two words contaminating one another, forming a mutually infected new one!

*Contaminaties* in everyday language can be divided into three categories:

1. a one-off slip of the tongue
2. established *contaminaties* (implemented over time)
3. deliberate mixtures

A *contaminatie* explicitly means the blending of words that carry a similar meaning orginally--like stampede and trample.

Comment: @fev That's an unfair comment to a new contributor who has come the closest of anyone to finding the actual *English* word. Maybe using Dutch here is not pedantically correct, but it leaves a breadcrumb for us to follow. For those interested, here's the English translation of the wikipedia article on the subject: https://nl-m-wikipedia-org.translate.goog/wiki/Contaminatie_(taal)?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en. FWIW, I really appreciate the contribution, and it gives me some hope that we'll eventually find the answer.

Comment: Ok, my bad. Still the information you kindly provide should be a comment, not an answer. I understand you don't have enough rep to post a comment so fair enough. My apologies for my laziness to explain this in the first place, did not mean to offend. Will delete my first comment in a bit. Be welcome.

Comment: @fev great response. It does look like this user created a brand new SE account, https://stackexchange.com/users/29080433/anouk, which we can presume was just to help out here. I can understand the frustration for a new user at SE, where all the low-hanging fruit is picked. 15 years on, there's no easy route to getting sufficient rep to start unlocking features such as commenting.

Comment: @KennSebesta I never understood this policy, but well, it is what is... And I also had to deal with some negativity as a new comer, but some are more thick-skinned than others, I suppose... I stuck around and I don't regret it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the term you’re looking for is  “Freudian Slip” which can encompass a “spoonerism”. You can find an online article here: https://www.healthline.com/health/freudian-slip

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm sure it's not "Freudian Slip", because that for sure I would have remembered. I learned what a Freudian Slip was the hard way at a tender adolescent age when I said to my family, "I think I'll finish eating my pizza now", only the word "pizza" was not the one which came out. :O

Answer (score 0):

Could you possibly be thinking of the word [Spoonerism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoonerism)? It doesn't an mean involuntary portmanteau, which is what you've described; it means switching consonants between two words, like saying *plading traces* instead of *trading places*.

Comment: Alas, not. Check out DjinTonic's excellent comment, https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/572931/what-is-it-called-when-a-speaker-accidentally-merges-two-words/610503#comment1427663_572931,  describing how this is different from many of the other terms which describe intentional modifications. In this case, I'm looking for accidental one-off slips.